# Invalid value for 'manifest_version'. Must be an integer greater than zero

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

```
{
    "name": "Park_School",
    "version":"2",
    "manifest_version":"2",
    "icons": { "128": "128.png" },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
             "http://vle.parkcommunity.devon.sch.uk/"
        ],
        "launch": {
             "web_url": "http://vle.parkcommunity.devon.sch.uk/"
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the manifest version is greater than zero but google chrome says it's not. Help?

Answer (score 3):

The value of `"manifest_version"` must be an **integer**; you have provided a **string**.

To solve the problem, replace `"manifest_version": "2"` with `"manifest_version": 2`.

Answer (score 1):

manifest_version should be an integer value. Please visit [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) for more detail.

so your configuration should be :

```
{
    "name": "Park_School",
    "version":"2",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "icons": { "128": "128.png" },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
             "http://vle.parkcommunity.devon.sch.uk/"
        ],
        "launch": {
             "web_url": "http://vle.parkcommunity.devon.sch.uk/"
        }
    }
}
```